# Any advice on how to fix this Stack Overflow error? Java

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management, stack-overflow

While developing a simple auto generating game of war in my free time, I ran into a "StackOverFlow" error.

Here is my Deck class where the error occurs:
It occurs in my compare() method. Any insight as to what I can do to avoid this error is accepted as I am struggling to understand what can be done to fix this and have little knowledge as to what this error even means besides my class doesn't have recursion done well. Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Deck
{
    private int num = 0;
    private int cardnum2 = 0;
    private int cardnum = 0;
    private int decrease = 0;
    private int rnd = 0;
    private int winner = 0;
    private String suit = " ";
    private int suitNum = 0;
    private int val = 1;
    private String name = "";
    private ArrayList<Card> Deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private Card[] cardCheck = new Card[51];
    private ArrayList<Card> play1 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private ArrayList<Card> play2 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    public Deck()
    {
        createDeck();
    }
    public void createDeck()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            val = 1;
            suit = " ";
            name = " ";
            suitNum++;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            for(int z  = 0; z < 13; z++)
            {
                if(suitNum == 1)
                {
                    suit = "Hearts";
                }
                if(suitNum == 2)
                {
                    suit = "Diamonds";
                }
                if(suitNum == 3)
                {
                    suit = "Spades";
                }
                if(suitNum == 4)
                {
                    suit = "Clubs";
                }
                if(val == 1)
                {
                    name = "Ace";
                }
                else if(val == 11)
                {
                    name = "Jack";
                }
                else if(val == 12)
                {
                    name = "Queen";
                }
                else if(val == 13)
                {
                    name = "King";
                }
                else {
                    name = "";
                }
                Card myCards = new Card(val, suit, name);
                Deck.add(myCards);
                System.out.print(myCards + "   ");
                val++;
            }
        }
    }
        public void Deal()
        {
            int size = 52 / 2;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                    Random();
                    for(int z = 0; z < cardCheck.length; z++)
                    {
                        if(cardCheck[i] == null)
                        {
                            cardCheck[i] = Deck.get(rnd);
                            play1.add(cardCheck[i]);
                            System.out.println(play1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Random();
                        }
                    } 
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                Deck.remove(play1.get(i));
            }
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    play2.add(Deck.get(i));
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)

            {
                System.out.println(play2.get(i));
            }   
    }
    public void Random()
    {
        rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 52) - decrease;
    }

    public void flip()
    {
        if(play1.indexOf(cardnum) >= play1.size() || play2.indexOf(cardnum2) >= play2.size())
        {
        cardnum = (int)(Math.random() * play1.size());
        System.out.println(play1.get(cardnum));
        cardnum2 = (int)(Math.random() * play2.size());
        System.out.println(play2.get(cardnum2));
      }
     }
     public void compare()
     {
        System.out.println("War!!!\n");
        if(play1.get(cardnum).getNum() > play2.get(cardnum2).getNum())
        {
            System.out.println();
            winner = 1;
            System.out.println(play1.get(cardnum) + " vs " + play2.get(cardnum2));
            play1.add(play2.get(cardnum2));
            play2.remove(cardnum2);
            System.out.println("Player 1 took the cards!");
            System.out.println();
            printDecks();
        }
        if(play1.get(cardnum).getNum() < play2.get(cardnum2).getNum())
        {
            System.out.println();
            winner = 2;
            System.out.println(play1.get(cardnum) + " vs " + play2.get(cardnum2));
            play2.add(play1.get(cardnum));
            play1.remove(cardnum);
            System.out.println("Player 2 took the cards!");
            System.out.println();
            printDecks();
           }
        if(play1.get(cardnum).getNum() == play2.get(cardnum2).getNum())
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(play1.get(cardnum) + " vs " + play2.get(cardnum2));
            System.out.println("War!!");
            winner = 0;
            flip();
            flip();
            flip();
            compare();
            System.out.println();
            printDecks();
         }
        }

    public void playW()
    {
        while(play1.size() > 0 || play2.size() > 0)
        {
            flip();
            compare();
        }
    }
    public void printDecks()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < play1.size(); i++)
        {   
            System.out.print(play1.get(i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < play2.size(); i++)
        {   
            System.out.print(play2.get(i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Player 1 has: " + play1.size() + " cards");
        System.out.println("Player 2 has: " + play2.size() + " cards");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't call `compare()` ***within*** the `compare()` method. Also why are you giving a class, Deck, a field of the same name, the Deck ArrayList? That will confuse all of us as well as the future-you.

Comment: Having said this, your whole program structure is broken as you're indiscriminately mixing user interface with your key structural classes. Re-write this, and get the user interface out of Deck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry about the names.... I am new to java and have established some poor habits that I need to break :/ So would you recommend I write a separate method in the case there is a war and use my compare() method there? Thanks, this was my first fully independent project and I didn't plan it too well but at least it has been a learning experience :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do I need to move the user interface into my driver program? Thanks!

Comment: A compare method should do one thing: compare two entities, whatever they are, nothing more and nothing less. Often they are written to return an int, +1, or positive for where the first is greater than the second, -1 or negative for the opposite, and 0 for when they compare to be the same. It doesn't get user interaction, it doesn't change the state of anything as a side effect. And yes, the user interface should be either part of the driver program, if simple, or a separate class or set of classes that are hooked up in the driver class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am sorry I am a beginner and I understand the compare() method now that you told me but how should I break up my code like you were explaining to the user interface so I can salvage my program. Do you recommend just restarting? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should restart.

Answer (score 1):

> and have little knowledge as to what this error even means besides my class doesn't have recursion done well.

Yes, your code has recursion, and it's easy to find. You know that the problem is coming from within the compare method, and so all you have to do is look within that method for `compare()` and find out where you're having the method call itself.

The solution is not to call the method within itself, and why should it be doing this anyway?

You're having the issue partly because your class structure is broken. The Deck class is class that should represent the structure and behavior of a deck of cards, nothing more and nothing less, It should have methods like `public void shuffle()`, like `public Card Deal()`, and such. It should not have any code that directly interacts with the user, and this code should go elsewhere, perhaps in your driver or Game class, or even as separate class(es) entirely.

I'm guessing that you'll also want to have a Hand class, one that holds a player's hand, and perhaps inside of this class, have a compare method that compares the current Hand with another Hand, passed in as a parameter.

You'll also want a Game class should have a game-loop that controls play, that ends when there is a winner or a draw, that holds the Deck, that holds 1 or more Player objects...

e.g.,

```
public enum Suit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES
}
```

```
public enum Value {
    //.... 
}
```

```
public class Card {
    private Suit suit;
    private Value value;

    // TODO: constructor, methods including equals, hashCode
}
```

```
public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    public Card deal() {
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collection.shuffle(cards);
    }

    //....

}
```

```
class Player {
    // either use a List in each Player or create a class called hand
    private List<Card> hand;
    private int cash;
    private String name;
    private Game game;

    // TODO: constructor
    // TODO: methods including receiveCard(Card c), List<Card> showHand(),...
}
```

```
public class Game {
    private Player p1;
    private Player p2;
    private Deck deck;
    private int moneyPot;
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel a little discouraged but I think I can restart and be up to speed quickly. Good learning curve and I think this will fuel my motivation to continue to improve.

Comment: Having a project a little above your abilities is the best way to progress. Don't hesitate to show your code to other developers to help you fix your bad habits. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment but it became too long.

There is a lot to say about this code. Use switch case instead of series of if. Or at least use if else. What is the point of a for loop if you use cases inside? What is the 'i' variable for if you then increment yourself a suitNum variable? Don't use capital letter for methods. Only classes. Why does Random edits a variable and returns void? It would be more logical that random() returns the result you want and this way you get free of the useless variable 'rnd'

There is a lot more to say but it is a good start. About your error, in short, a stack overflow means that your program is using too much memory. This is especially common in code that contains an infinite recursive loop. Here, the infinite recursion is due to the compare method called inside the compare method...